# Get distances between boundaries from an SpatialPolygon and raster pixels

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance from several pixels of a raster to a boundary of some polygons in R as it is showed in the image. I have two problems:

1. How to correctly define a boundary from a `SpatialPolygon` object. I currently have two options, but I can not decide for which is the best one. First, I can coerce the `SpatialPolygon` `as` a `SpatialLines` object and then to SpatialPoints. Second, I can `raster::rasterize` the `SpatialPolygon`. I suppose each option has its pros and cons.
2. I only want make the distance calculation from one of the sides of the border. In the example, I only want the distance to the border from the pixels inside Colombia to the border between both countries. I tried to "filter" the border using a latitude parameter but the real border is quite irregular, so using a strict cut-off value can lead to error.

The following code can be used to get the a example shapefile:

```
#Get the world map and select two countries [Colombia and Venezuela]
library(maptools) #To get the shp data 
data(wrld_simpl)
colven <- c("Colombia", "Venezuela")
colven_map <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME %in% colven, ]
```

Raster data can be created with this code:

```
raster <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, crs=proj4string(wrld_simpl))
raster_extent <- extent(colven_map)
raster <- setExtent(raster, raster_extent)
raster[] <- 1:length(raster)
raster_colven <- mask(raster, coven)
raster_colven <- crop(raster, colven_map)
raster_colven <- mask(raster_colven, colven_map)
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you've already found an answer but this is how I would do it.

1. I would use `rgeos::gIntersection` for two adjacent polygons.
2. I'm assuming you'd like the distance from centroid of each raster cell
   to the border.  I basically use `raster::rasterToPoints` and
   `rgeos::gDistance` to find the distance from the shared border 
   and the raster centroids.

I also use `raster::getData` to use GADM boundaries instead of `maptools`.

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
colombia <- raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "CO", level = 0)
venezuela <- raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "VE", level = 0)
venezuela <- sp::spChFIDs(venezuela, "2") # Unique IDs for join
colven <- maptools::spRbind(colombia, venezuela)
border <- rgeos::gIntersection(colombia, venezuela)
```

Get the raster cell centers by country

```
raster <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, crs=proj4string(colven))
raster <- setExtent(raster, extent(colven))
raster_points <- raster::rasterToPoints(raster, spatial = TRUE)
colombia_points <- raster_points[colombia, ]
venezuela_points <- raster_points[venezuela, ]
```

Project and calculate distance with `rgeos::gDistance`.  I'm using the equidistant cylindrical projection and kilometers.

```
crs.edc <- CRS("+proj=eqc +lat_ts=60 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs")

rgeos::gDistance(spTransform(colombia_points, crs.edc),
                 spTransform(border, crs.edc), byid = TRUE)
rgeos::gDistance(spTransform(venezuela_points, crs.edc),
                 spTransform(border, crs.edc), byid = TRUE)
```

Plot

```
pch <- "."
plot(colven)
plot(colombia_points, pch = pch, add = TRUE, col = "green")
plot(venezuela_points, pch = pch, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
plot(border, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

Hopefully this helps

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you sboysel, I used a similar approach. Nonetheless, now that you mention it, which command you will use if the polygons were not adjacent, but one on top of the other one?

Comment: `gIntersection` would simply return the intersection of two polygons.  Depending on your objective, perhaps some use of `gDifference` will give you a workable border between to polygons.  I've never done this personally.